# GET https://mydomain.server:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: node.js, laravel, socket.io, port, laravel-echo

I'm trying to work with socket.io first time. 
I'm using Laravel 5.4, Laravel Echo and [NodeJs server for Laravel Echo broadcasting with Socket.io.](https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server).

I managed to make it work on my local as it supposed to work. But on server I get 
an error

```
GET https://mydomain.server:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I do run the server before. I write correct address. 
[image]

May be browser doesn't have access to that port or something?

Also I tried to access to the file with 
`curl -X GET https://mydomain.server:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js` command.

But got 
`curl: (35) gnutls_handshake() failed: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated`.

Comment: I'm also facing same issue on my server. But it is not related to https. My domain has http protocol. Can you tell me possibilities of error?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution.

Just set protocol, sslCertPath and sslKeyPath parameters in **laravel-echo-server.json**

```
"protocol": "https",
"sslCertPath": "path_to/server.crt",
"sslKeyPath": "path_to/server.key"
```

Answer (score 0):

> May be this will help you.
>   Firstly when you are connecting to socket and site is having ssl installed then use :

```
 socket = io.connect('http://example.com:port', {'force new connection': true, 'secure': true});
```

> Include above part in your script part on client side.
>
> Secondly on server side in your for eg : server.js say use

```
var https = require('https');
var server = https.createServer({
     key : fs.readFileSync('./sslkey.key'),
     cert : fs.readFileSync('./ssl_certificate.crt')
},app);
```

Comment: It could help me if I didn't use Laravel Echo Server. But it could definitely give me an idea how to fix that with Laravel Echo Server. I've already found the solution, check my answer below, if you're interested. Thanks